# Django Rest Framework - Serializing data of reverse related table which depends on another reverse relation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

```
class Admin(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=189)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=189)

class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=189)

class AdminPage(models.Model):
    user = models.OnetoOneField(User, related_name="connected_page", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name="connected_users", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="messages", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here, I want to serialize a list of pages which will contain a list of connected users. e.g.

```
{
    "pages": [
    {
        "name": "XXX", 
        "users": [
            {
                "username": "Sad User",
                "status": "active",
            }, 
            {
                "username": "Sleepy User",
                "status": "idle",
            }
         ]
     }
]
}
```

Here, each user can only be connected to one page at the same time. The status of a connected user will be active if the AdminPage connection was created within 30 minutes, and will become inactive if the user has no messages in the last 30 minutes. (A user connected to a page an hour ago but a message 2 minutes ago will be active).

I want to solve this problem using Django and the DjangoRestFrameowrk (DRF) with the least number of queries. Currently I am using a serializermethodfield to do this, but this created an additional query on each user which I want to avoid.

Is there any way I can accomplish this? Any thoughts are appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT**
I am providing the serializer snippet, but I don't think what I have done is the right way to do this.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField("_status")
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "status"]
     def _status(self, obj):
         check_active = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=30)
         check_inactive = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
         last_admin_interaction = obj.messages.last()
         if last_admin_interaction:
             last_interaction_time = last_admin_interaction.created_at
         else:
             last_interaction_time = None
        if obj.current_platform.created_at > check_active:
             return "active"
        else:
            if not last_interaction_time:
                return "inactive"

            if last_interaction_time > check_active:
                return "active"
            else:
                if last_interaction_time > check_inactive:
                    return "idle"
                else:
                    return "inactive"

class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    connected_users = serializers.SerializerMethodField("_connected")
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ["name", "connected_users"]
    def _connected(self, obj):
        admins = obj.connected_users.values_list("user", flat=True)
        admins = Admin.objects.filter(id__in=admins)
        return UserSerializer(admins, read_only=True, many=True).data
```

Comment: can you add the  serializer snippet?

Comment: edited, before calling I am also using prefetch_related with the queryset.
qs = Page.objects.prefetch_related("connected_users", "connected_users__user", "connected_users__user__messages")

Comment: Your `SerializerMethodField` seems very long. Usually `SerializerMethodField` used for these kinds of situations.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I can solve this situation if I can do something similar to a group_by over here on the table AdminPage, where I will group the admins based on the page! But I'm not sure how to proceed with this (or if it'll even work!)

Comment: Why are you rewriting into `admins` again in method `_connected`?
I dont see any attribute named `connected_admins` on `Page` object.
What are `admin_interactions` on `User` object?
Mention any repetitive queries that you found.

Comment: @SachinKukreja that was a typing error on my part. Sorry about that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround on this. I annotated two new fields on an AdminPage queryset, last_message_time (using SubQuery) and status (using the fields created_at and last_message time and creating a Case->When conditional expression).

```
states = AdminPage.objects.select_related("page", "user").annotate(
    last_message=Subquery(Interaction.objects.filter(admin=OuterRef("user_id")).values("created_at").order_by("-created_at")[:1])).annotate(
        admin_status=Case(When(Q(created_at__gt=active_time) | Q(last_message__gt=active_time), then=Value('active')), When(Q(created_at__gt=inactive_time) | Q(last_message__gt=inactive_time), then=Value('idle')), default=Value('inactive'), output_field=CharField())
)
```

I pass this queryset to a new serializer which does the job!